# Get the final data from angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

In my angular 6 application i am having a `product_id` which is an array,

`product_id: any = ["123", "456"];`

**ngOnInit :**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.product_id.forEach(element => {
      this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc').subscribe(res => {
        this.productList = [];
        res.products.forEach( item => {
          this.productList.push(item);
        });
      })
    })
    console.log(this.productList);
  }
```

Here in `console.log(this.productList);`, i need to have the **expected result** as,

```
   [{
      "product_name": "Product One",
      "product_information": {
        "template_details": [
          {
            "template_name": "RACE Template",
            "productProperties": [
              {
                "property_id": 2518427931,
                "property_name": "Length",
                "property_value": "12 cm"
              },
              {
                "property_id": 2621195440,
                "property_name": "Width",
                "property_value": "10 cm"
              },
              {
                "property_id": 2621195441,
                "property_name": "Height",
                "property_value": "20 cm"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "product_name": "Product Two",
      "product_information": {
        "template_details": [
          {
            "template_name": "RACE Template",
            "productProperties": [
              {
                "property_id": 2518427931,
                "property_name": "Length",
                "property_value": "15 cm"
              },
              {
                "property_id": 2621195440,
                "property_name": "Width",
                "property_value": "12 cm"
              },
              {
                "property_id": 2621195441,
                "property_name": "Size",
                "property_value": "Medium"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
```

But which gives **empty array []**..

How to wait for the service to complete and then store the data into `productList`..

I am in the need of forEach, `this.product_id.forEach(element` as because in my real application based on the foreach i will get the product list for each product id sent via url..

Kindly help me to store the data after completion of entire service based on `forEach` after all the product id sent then get the final product list..

**Working stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-dvzpjv

**Once again i am making it clear** that in my real application i need to pass the id to get the `product value` like `https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc + element`..

Also if i get the final `productList` then i need to do another functionality with the final `productList` so only i am expecting completed data in `productList` at last and not inside `forEach`..

Comment: I do not see you are using element variable while calling API. Is there any reason for having for loop on product_id ?
You are also setting this.productList to empty array inside response, which means after every response it will clear the previous results.

Comment: `console.log(this.productList);` is logged after an **async** block, hence it's evaluated **BEFORE** the request takes place. You should log it **inside** the subscribe callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @VikramkumarChhajer, I am in the need of foreach like that because in my real applicatio i have like that.. Also explained in the question..

Comment: @briosheje, I need to get the final result if i give it inside it loops according to foreach count.. BUt also i need the service inside foreach as because in my real application i have like that..

Comment: Also if i get the final ```productList``` then i need to do another functionality with the final ```productList``` so only i am expecting completed data..

Comment: use `Promise` for that case, or register an event (a callback) or, eventually, use forkJoin: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html . You need to fire a callback once **every** request has been completed and **join** the results you received.

Answer (score 1):

use rxjs.concat :

[edit]

available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zacfdo)

```
...
import { concat } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

ngOnInit() {
  this.productList = [];
  concat(
    this.product_id.map(
      element => this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc')
    )
  ).pipe(
    map((res: any) => this.productList = this.productList.concat(res.products))
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(this.productList);
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This would work:

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs'
....
ngOnInit() {
  const obs = []
  this.product_id.forEach(element => {
    obs.push(this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc'))
  })
  zip(...obs).subscribe(res => {
    res.forEach(r => this.productList.push(...r.products))
    console.log(this.productList)
  })
}
```

**stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-nk9yha

Comment: Read my edited question.. This is not solution in my case, i need to have finalresult ascompleted data outside ```foreach```..

Comment: Please make console.log,       ```this.productList = res
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productList));``` it gives ```product one``` two times..

Comment: @undefined Finally I have understood what you want.
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-nk9yha](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-nk9yha)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: you log that too soon, and you overwrite the array.

First, the log to soon. You fire off requests (`ids.forEach(id => this.http....)`). Then right after that, you do a `console.log` - but the results are not back yet. Requests haven't been even fired yet, likely. That's why you see the empty array. Move the console.log statement right under `this.productList.push(...)` statement, you'll see the thing.

The second issue is that you fire parallel requests and they both *reset the product list* with this line: `this.productList = []`;.

You want to do that only once.

A better version of this all would be:

```
ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin(product_ids) // fire them in parallel.
    .pipe(
       map(id => this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc' + id)),   // fetch the things
       map(items=> this.productList = this.productList.concat(items)),
    )
    .subscribe(() => console.log('Done, items:', this.productList));
```

Even better version would be:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getProductItems(productIds)
        .subscribe(productList => this.productList = productList);
}
```

Meaning, move your Http calls into a service, do all this stuff there, and keep your component cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185489/discussion-on-answer-by-zlatko-get-the-final-data-from-angular-service).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a real service as described in angular documentation ?

here you want to implement httpClient direclty within a component
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

i would suggest you to first create an Injectable service, that will be used in the component constructor like your httpClient

Then, I would get the data in the service, and subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let counter = 0;
    this.productList = [];
    this.product_id.forEach(element => {
      this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc').subscribe(res => {
        res.products.forEach( item => {
          this.productList.push(item);
        });
        counter = counter + 1;
        if(counter === this.product_id.length){
            console.log(this.productList);  
            // call your next operation here
        }
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: In your solution, ```console.log(this.productList);``` gives four objects.. Means ```Product One``` and also ```Product Two``` occurs multiple (two) times..

Comment: thats because I am not passing element id in API call. So API responding two objects in each call. So If i am calling API two times, i will be having 4 objects.
You need to call API specific to particular id.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-kpetre?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

....

ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
      this.product_id.map(element => this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc'))
    )
    .subscribe((res) => {
        this.productList = this.productList.concat(res);
        console.log(this.productList);
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to get only two objects ```Product One``` and ```Product Two``` in final result.. Your solution gives both two times.. Using foreach if service call is made then i need to get that json alone in single time and no duplicate values..

Comment: @undefined I don't quite understand what you mean. There are two IDs so it will make two get requests, which will then be merged into one response. I updated my stackblitz. Check it out and tell me if one of the arrays suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This would works as well:

```
this.productList$ = from(this.product_id).pipe(
    mergeMap(() =>  this.httpClient.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hiolc')),
    scan((productList, item) => [...productList, item], [])
    tap((productList) => console.log(productList))
).subscribe(() => {}) // or async pipe in a template
```